# How to depict several sub-options in use case diagrams

Tags: uml, use-case

Shown in the image below is an example of an actor that can perform an action and this action branches into several options (none of them HAVE to be performed). My question is whether the arrows coming from "Manage my events" should be "include" or "extend". In other words, is "include" or "extend" more appropriate if I want to depict a use case branching out into other optional use cases?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you take a look at UML Specification.

> **Include** : An Include relationship specifies that a UseCase contains the behavior defined in another UseCase.

and

> **Extend** : A relationship from an extending UseCase to an extended UseCase that specifies how and when the behavior defined in
>   the extending UseCase can be inserted into the behavior defined in the extended UseCase.

So your example means that when a user "manage my event", he **always** (includes) "Update event", "Add event", and "Invite participant".

I guess that you wanted to model the fact that "manage my event", **may be extended**  by "Update event", "Add event", and "Invite participant". If I am right, "Extend" relationship would be better cf below.

[image]

Comment: as a second thought, won't inheritance fit this case more? I mean, make "Update event", "Add event" and "Invite participants" inherit from "Manage my events" instead of extending it.

Comment: It is possible.... I would recommand you to describe your use cases. 
If your actor has a "Manage my events" use case and in some case this managing is extended by adding an event, keep your current modelling.